# Convert QTextStream to QByteArray

Tags: qt, qbytearray, qtextstream

I need to convert a QTextStream to a QByteArray, and then back again.  I found an example of QTextStream -> QByteArray by constructing a QTextStream(QBytearray) and then any text < < to the stream ends up in the bytearray.

But how about the other way?  Probably a one liner but I can figure it out.  Can someone post and explain?

Answer (score 0):

Check it out if your text stream works via file (maybe via socket):

```
QFile file(fileName);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) 
   return;

QTextStream in(&file);
QString text;    

text = in.readAll();
file.close();

text.QString::toUtf8(); //convert your data to byte array
```

To get your data back use: `QString::fromUtf8(const QByteArray &str)`